# using reg exps in Python

Tags: python

I used

```
"<a href='/property-(.+?)-wa[a-zA-Z0-9-\s\" ]{5,50}><img src="
```

to get the type of property in [webpage that I want to analyze](https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-perth+-+greater+region,+wa/list-1)

and I can get these message by using regex to analyze code like this:

```
<a href="/property-house-wa-joondalup-405127028" ><img src=
```

It is
`"<a href='/property-` + house(what I want)+`-wa`+ 5-50 chars,numbers,",space +`><img src=`

I tested it in visualization tool and it seems to be OK

[image]

But the output is empty when running code

code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

url='https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-perth+-+greater+region,+wa/list-1'
page = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
##print(page)
propertyReg=re.compile(r"<a href='/property-(.+?)-wa[a-zA-Z0-9-\s\" ]{5,50}><img src=")
propertytext=re.findall(propertyReg,page)
print(propertytext)
```

Comment: [Have you tried using an HTML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761)

Comment: Try `r"<a href=\"/property-(.+?)-wa[a-zA-Z0-9-\s\"]{5,50}><img src="`. Double quote in front of `/property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your regexp:

Instead of

```
"<a href='/property-(.+?)-wa[a-zA-Z0-9-\s\" ]{5,50}><img src="
```

, it should be:

```
"<a href=['\"]/property-(.+?)-wa[a-zA-Z0-9-\s\" ]{5,50}><img src="
```

(bot `'` and `"` match after `href=`)

Regular expressions may be a bit daunting to work with if you need many of them in complicated scenarios. This may be better to use a html parser and match against its results instead. This avoids mistakes, like the one you made, because parser handles attribute values extraction for you.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid parsing html data using regex. Use something specifically built for this like Beautiful soup

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> url='https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-perth+-+greater+region,+wa/list-1'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
>>> for a in soup.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'^/property')}):
>>>     property = a['href'].split('-', 2)[1]
>>>     print (property)
```